# Get sympy to pprint sin(a_n) with s(a_n)

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbols, trigonometry, pprint

I'm trying to get sympy to pprint matrices with trig functions with the first letter instead of the shortened term in order to save space. So sin(a_1) will look like sa_1. Right now I'm printing to text then running a find and replace. (I'm new to programming.) So far, this is what does not work:

```
from sympy import sin as s
from sympy import cos as c

# declaring symbolic variables:
sin, cos, = sym.symbols('s, c')

  #An example Matrix
  T = Matrix([[c(theta), -s(theta), 0, a],
                [s(theta) * c(alpha), c(theta) * c(alpha), -s(alpha), -s(alpha) * d],
                [s(theta) * s(alpha), c(theta) * s(alpha), c(alpha), c(alpha) * d],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])
#T04 was a sympy symbol matrix solution 
T_000 = str(print_latex(T04))
T_000 = str(T04)
T_000 = T_000.replace('sin', 's')
T_000 = T_000.replace('cos', 'c')
print('T000\n')
pprint(T_000)
T_001 = Matrix([[(-s(theta_1) * s(theta_2) + c(theta_1) * c(theta_2)) * c(theta_3) + (
            -s(theta_1) * c(theta_2) - s(theta_2) * c(theta_1)) * s(theta_3),
                 -(-s(theta_1) * s(theta_2) + c(theta_1) * c(theta_2)) * s(theta_3) + (
                             -s(theta_1) * c(theta_2) - s(theta_2) * c(theta_1)) * c(theta_3), 0,
                 L_1 * c(theta_1) + L_2 * (-s(theta_1) * s(theta_2) + c(theta_1) * c(theta_2))], [
                    (-s(theta_1) * s(theta_2) + c(theta_1) * c(theta_2)) * s(theta_3) + (
                                s(theta_1) * c(theta_2) + s(theta_2) * c(theta_1)) * c(theta_3),
                    (-s(theta_1) * s(theta_2) + c(theta_1) * c(theta_2)) * c(theta_3) - (
                                s(theta_1) * c(theta_2) + s(theta_2) * c(theta_1)) * s(theta_3), 0,
                    L_1 * s(theta_1) + L_2 * (s(theta_1) * c(theta_2)
                                              + s(theta_2) * c(theta_1))], [0, 0, 1, d_4], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
print('\nT001\n')
pprint(T_001)

T_000.replace(sin, s)
print('T000\n', T_000)
```

It's always printing with the full "sin" and "cos" names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to replace functions in an expression(in this case the expression is the matrix `T`). One is to use the [`replace`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) function, the other is to use the [`subs`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs) function. Any of the two can be used to achieve the same goal of replacing sin/cos with other functions.

In the code below we're replacing the function `s` (which is an alias to `sin`) with the undefined function `s1` (whose symbolic name is `s`).
The same happens with `c` and `c1`.

```py
from sympy import *

# s,c act as aliases to sin,cos
s = sin
c = cos

# the intended short-hand functions used to replace sin/cos later on
s1 = Function('s')
c1 = Function('c')

a,d,theta,alpha = symbols('a d \\theta \\alpha')

T = Matrix([
    [c(theta), -s(theta), 0, a],
    [s(theta) * c(alpha), c(theta) * c(alpha), -s(alpha), -s(alpha) * d],
    [s(theta) * s(alpha), c(theta) * s(alpha), c(alpha), c(alpha) * d],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
])

T_1 = T.replace(s,s1).replace(c,c1)
T_2 = T.subs({s:s1,c:c1})

display(T_1)
display(T_2)
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

The code used in this post is [also available here](https://github.com/wsdookadr/so/tree/master/so-66269049).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! Thank you! I was substituting incorrectly and not using an extra variable to describe the function. YAY!

Comment: I also didn't realize you could import everything with *. That's helpful. Thank you! But how did you use the "display" function? I changed to from sympy import * and it's giving me a return error of "'display' not defined

Comment: @Manju the `display` function was available because I ran all of this in a [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) notebook. Jupyter can be advantageous to iterate fast when using SymPy. About the call to `display`, it can also be replaced with `print`. There's a more detailed discussion of [printing in SymPy here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html).

Comment: Ahh, ok, I'm using pycharm. Thank you!!! **Just as a note for those who may do this later: substituting the function also removes the solving capability, for example sin(x) will no longer solve for sin(x) if x is substituted for, for example pi, later. So for printing purposes only, substitute the s1 function in a separate "for printing only" matrix.